# Prove that $\{x\in X : f(x)\leq g(x)\}$ is closed, order topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space, $Y$ be an ordered topological space
(see definition below) and $f,g: X\to Y$ be continuous maps. Prove
that:
a) $Y$ is the Hausdorff space.
b) $A=\{(y_1,y_2)\in Y\times Y:y_1<y_2\}$ is open in product topology $Y\times Y$.
c) $B=\{x\in X:f(x)\leq g(x)\}$ is closed in $X$.
d) The map $h: X\to Y$ defined by $$h(x)=\min\{f(x),g(x)\}$$ is continuous on $X$.

PS: Assume $(X,\leq)$ is the set with linear order (if $x,y$ in $X$ then $x\leq y$ or $y\leq x$). Denote $\mathbb{B}$ is a family of subsets of $X$ having one of $3$ following forms:

1. $\{x\in X|a<x<b\}$, $a,b\in X, a<b$.
2. $\{x\in X|x<a\}$, $a\in X$.
3. $\{x\in X|a<x\}$, $a\in X$.

We knew that $\mathbb{B}$ is a base of some $\tau$ in $X$ and $(X,\tau)$ is called as the ordered topological space.

I already finished part a),b) but stuck at c). Here's my attempt for c)
We need to prove $G=X\setminus B=\{x\in X|f(x)>g(x)\}$ is open in $X$.
Consider $x\in G$. Then $f(x)>g(x)$. Since $Y$ is Hausdoff, there exist an open nbh $U'$ of $f(x)$ and $V'$ of $g(x)$ s.t $U'\cap V'=\varnothing$
Also, since $f,g$ are continuous, there exists open nbhs $U,V$ of $x$ s.t $f(U)\subset U', g(V)\subset V'$.
Define $W=U\cap V$. Then $W$ is an open nbh of $x$. I need to show that $W\subset G$, then I can conclude $G$ is open.
Consider $y\in W$. Then $f(y)\in U',g(y)\in V'$, together with $U'\cap V'=\varnothing$, we deduce $f(y)\neq g(y)$. But how can I show $f(y)>g(y)$? Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In fact, which is a much harder fact to prove, $Y$ is a $T_5$ space (but not necessarily $T_6$).

Comment: Can you think of a way to relate the sets $A$ and $B$ using a continuous map?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Not yet. Could u show me?

Comment: If you have a question about part d), you need to make another question on this site. This is the policy here, as well as one question per question (keep it focused). You can't change your question midway (unless, perhaps, nobody has answered you - I did, see below).

Answer (score 3):

You can just use b) to prove c).

b) implies that the set $\{(y_1, y_2)\in Y^2 : y_1 \leq y_2\}$ is closed. Of course, that's not directly implied by b), but since the map $(y_1, y_2)\mapsto (y_2, y_1)$ is a homeomorphism of $Y^2$, its true.

Consider the map given by $h(x) = (f(x), g(x))$, then $h:X\to Y^2$ is continuous and so $$h^{-1}(\{(y_1, y_2)\in Y^2 : y_1 \leq y_2\}) = \{x\in X : f(x)\leq g(x)\} = B$$ is  closed set.

Comment: Could u explain why the map $(y_1,y_2)\mapsto (y_2,y_1)$ is a homeomorphism of $Y^2$?

Comment: @AlexNguyen sure. Do you see why $(y_1, y_2)\mapsto (y_2, y_1)$ is continuous? If you see that, then notice that if you compose this map with itself, you obtain the identity map on $Y^2$. So this map has a continuous inverse - itself.

Comment: How can I show that map is continous?

Comment: @AlexNguyen The proof of that depends on what you know about the product topology. I've used this property of it: A map $f:Z\to \prod_{i\in I} Z_i$ is continuous iff $f\circ p_i:Z\to Z_j$ is continuous for all $j\in I$, where $p_j:\prod_{i\in I} Z_i\to Z_j$ denotes the map $p_j(z) = z_j$. The maps here are $(y_1, y_2)\mapsto y_1$ and $(y_1, y_2)\mapsto y_2$ which are projections, their continuity implies continuity of $(y_1, y_2)\mapsto (y_2, y_1)$.